Codeignitor session values are not exist when redirect to next page
I'm facing an issue in production after upgrading to PHP 8.2 where session values are missing when navigating between pages. These values only appear after multiple clicks or form submissions. I need your assistance to resolve this issue, Ryan.

which CI version?

I am using the CI 3.1.11

try updating to 3.1.13 (latest and last), there have been some session related bugs dealt with: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html?highlight=session
